# How to sort an arrays of pointers, without changing the original array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, numbers

Given two arrays: int nums[N] and int *ptrs[N] (N is a constant number).
I have to initialize the first array with some numbers. After that, i have to initialize the second array, so every element of the second array points to the element with the same index of the first array. (ptrs[0] points to nums[0],...).

Now i have to write a function with "ptrs" as argument that modifies the pointers in such a way that the first element of the second array points to the smallest number in the first array,..)

It's not allowed to change the "nums-array", i can only change the "ptrs-array".

This is my code i already have, but when i run it, the "nums-array" changes too.
What do i do wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define N 6
    void sort(int *ptrs);
    int main()
    {
        int nums[N] = { 1,6,7,8,2,5 };
        int(*ptrs)[N];
        int i;
        ptrs = nums;



        sort(ptrs);

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)



            printf("nummer is: %d en %d\n", (*ptrs)[i], nums[i]);


         return 0;
      }
      void sort(int *ptrs)
      {
        int i, j, tmp;


        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)

            for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)

                if ((ptrs)[i] > (ptrs)[j])
                {
                    tmp = (ptrs)[i];
                    (ptrs)[i] = (ptrs)[j];
                    (ptrs)[j] = tmp;
                }

      }
```

Comment: `ptrs = nums;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: So what do i have to do, to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for the first part:

```
int main()
{
    int nums[N] = { 1,6,7,8,2,5 };
    int *ptrs[N];                    // fix
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)           // fix
        ptr[i] = nums+i;             // fix (or ptr[i] = &nums[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks for helping guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6
void sort(int ptrs[], int nums[]);

int main()
{
    int nums[N] = { 1,6,7,8,2,5 };

    int i,j,*p, *ptrs[N];


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
               ptrs[i] = &nums[i];
    }




    sort(ptrs, nums);



        return 0;
}
void sort(int *ptrs[], int nums[])
{
    int i, j, tmp, p[N];


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        p[i] = *ptrs[i];




    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)


            if (p[i] > p[i+1])
            {
                tmp = (ptrs)[i];
                (ptrs)[i] = (ptrs)[i+1];
                (ptrs)[i+1] = tmp;
                for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                    p[i] = *ptrs[i];

           }


        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            printf("nummer is: %d en %d\n", *ptrs[i], nums[i]);
        return;

}
```

Comment: You welcome, I am sorry for not providing a complete solution, since this was a school project. However, you have one more issue with your code:  You have gone from a poor sorting algorithm N squared to N cubed. Try and move the last loop outside the i and j loops.